# Digital Broadcasting - settop box

Tags: mpeg

I'm very new to settop box project.Is there any materials  available to study the basics of its internals and the working of it.I dont know how to start understand about it.I was looking for the  architecture of middleware,DCCM and other components.I need to know how these components interact with each other.I need to know how by pressing a particular event in the EPG menu we could able to get the event corresponding to the service.I need to know the interaction between the tables.How to set the reminder in EPG and how the interactive TV works.

Comment: This is a very broad question. It sounds like you're asking for documentation for the project you're working on ("its internals and the working of it", "how these components interact with each other").

Comment: I wanted to know whether what i have thought about broadcasting is right or wrong.The events(programs) are sent by particular services(channels) to the broadcaster with each services at different services.The broadcaster collects all the services(channels) and its events and multiplexes them and sends all the services collected as a single frequency.This is done at the transmitter side and at the receiver side through the demultiplexer the services(channels) are then got at different frequncies and stored in the database with some unique identification called PID values.Is this correct.

Comment: My confusion is after demultiplexing will the services be got in different frequenices.How to differentiate the minor and major numbers.

Comment: It's a very broad subject, I could not even give a brief overview in a comment or an answer. I suggest you look online for "introduction to digital television", something like http://www.interactivetvweb.org/tutorials/dtv_intro/dtv_intro would be useful for you. I think you're missing the big picture, so there's little point in explaining details (such as why PIDs are useless for distinguishing between services).

Comment: @omrib:The website is very useful to me.Thanks for directing me to go in the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only a very partial answer to your question. Rather i would say, this is the first preliminary work you must accomplish before getting deeper into interactivity.

The tutorial here on [PSIP: Program specific information](http://www.bitrouter.com/pdf/tutorial-psip.pdf) show how the ATSC (or DVB is similar) is organized in the form of periodic tables including some tables that indicate EPG. By reading and processing such tables you will be able to accomplish the desired work.

Essentially, EPG table contains the information about the program and its respective time. And the actual timing information is contained in the TDT and TOT table. These tables tells the STB's the current time (on wall clock). Once, the respective time occurs, as per the TDT/TOT, the notification action can fire.

Below here are two more important references to Transport stream structures.

1. [PSIP tutorial](http://pds3.egloos.com/pds/200611/14/24/psip-tutorial.pdf)
2. [The ATSC transport layer, including program and system information protocol (PSIP)](http://www.tijbc.com/pruebas-7419/I0782907.pdf)

Please read the above pre-requsite and then refine your question.

Comment: :Thank you so much dude. The links you have said here are very very useful. Thanks for helping me friend.